# Anchor tag acts as a form submit button?

Tags: button, anchor

Anchor tag acts as a form submit button?

```
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
<div class="field-search">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search for..." value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
    <a href="#" class="btn-search"><i class="fa fa-search font-16"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What is your problem? What are you trying to do? What have you tried? How did your attempt not work? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does it? Or are you _trying_ to ask how to achieve that? In that case, have you tried to research this …? https://www.google.com/search?q=form+submit+via+anchor

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="test.aspx" type="POST">
    <label>
        <span>Username</span>
        <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" class="input-text required" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Password</span>
        <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" class="input-text required" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" id="RememberMe" class="check-box" />
        <span class="checkboxlabel">Remember Me</span>
    </label>
    <div class="spacer">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="login-button">Login</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on("click",".login-button",function(){
     var form = $(this).closest("form");
     //console.log(form);
     form.submit();
   });
});
```

possible duplicate of
([Anchor tag as submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098175/anchor-tag-as-submit-button))

(This is a copied answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach see if it works.

Add a click event to your anchor tag as below and do a event.stopPropagation()

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
})`
```

See if this works